# convert contents of metadata file into variables list

Tags: python, file, variables, metadata

Hi I m wanting to convert the contents of a file (in this case a Landsat 7 metadata file) into a series of variables defined by the contents of the file using Python 2.7. The file contents looks like this:

```
  GROUP = L1_METADATA_FILE
      GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
        ORIGIN = "Image courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey"
        REQUEST_ID = "0101305309253_00043"
        LANDSAT_SCENE_ID = "LE71460402010069SGS00"
        FILE_DATE = 2013-06-02T11:19:59Z
        STATION_ID = "SGS"
        PROCESSING_SOFTWARE_VERSION = "LPGS_12.2.1"
        DATA_CATEGORY = "NOMINAL"
      END_GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
      GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA
        DATA_TYPE = "L1T"
        ELEVATION_SOURCE = "GLS2000"
        OUTPUT_FORMAT = "GEOTIFF"
        EPHEMERIS_TYPE = "DEFINITIVE"
        SPACECRAFT_ID = "LANDSAT_7"
        SENSOR_ID = "ETM"
        SENSOR_MODE = "BUMPER"
        WRS_PATH = 146
        WRS_ROW = 040
        DATE_ACQUIRED = 2010-03-10

GROUP = IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES
    CLOUD_COVER = 0.00
    IMAGE_QUALITY = 9
    SUN_AZIMUTH = 137.38394502
    SUN_ELEVATION = 48.01114126
    GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_MODEL = 55
    GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL = 3.790
    GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_Y = 2.776
    GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_X = 2.580
  END_GROUP = IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES


    Example of interested variable items:

    GROUP = MIN_MAX_RADIANCE
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_1 = 293.700
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_1 = -6.200
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_2 = 300.900
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_2 = -6.400
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_3 = 234.400
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_3 = -5.000
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_4 = 241.100
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_4 = -5.100
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_5 = 47.570
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_5 = -1.000
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6_VCID_1 = 17.040
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_6_VCID_1 = 0.000
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6_VCID_2 = 12.650
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_6_VCID_2 = 3.200
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_7 = 16.540
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_7 = -0.350
        RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_8 = 243.100
        RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_8 = -4.700
      END_GROUP = MIN_MAX_RADIANCE
```

I am open to other ideas as I don't need all entries as variables, just a selection. And I see some headers are listed more than once. i.e. GROUP is used multiple times. I need to be able to select certain variables (integer values) and use in formulas in other areas of code. ANY help would be appreciated (novice python coder).

Comment: Is that really original data or a chop-job of different parts? I'm just asking because there's no END_GROUP for GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA and the enclosing tags for IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES aren't properly aligned.

Comment: Its a chop job. I thought the whole file was a bit to long to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but maybe something like this:

```
s = '''GROUP = L1_METADATA_FILE
  GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
    ORIGIN = "Image courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey"
    REQUEST_ID = "0101305309253_00043"
    LANDSAT_SCENE_ID = "LE71460402010069SGS00"
    FILE_DATE = 2013-06-02T11:19:59Z
    STATION_ID = "SGS"
    PROCESSING_SOFTWARE_VERSION = "LPGS_12.2.1"
    DATA_CATEGORY = "NOMINAL"
  END_GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
  GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA
    DATA_TYPE = "L1T"
    ELEVATION_SOURCE = "GLS2000"
    OUTPUT_FORMAT = "GEOTIFF"
    EPHEMERIS_TYPE = "DEFINITIVE"
    SPACECRAFT_ID = "LANDSAT_7"
    SENSOR_ID = "ETM"
    SENSOR_MODE = "BUMPER"
    WRS_PATH = 146
    WRS_ROW = 040
    DATE_ACQUIRED = 2010-03-10'''


output = {} #Dict
for line in s.split("\n"): #Iterates through every line in the string
    l = line.split("=") #Seperate by "=" and put into a list
    output[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip() #First word is key, second word is value

print output #Output is a dictonary containing all key-value pairs in your metadata seperated by "="

print output["SENSOR_ID"] #Outputs "ETM"
```

==============

Edited:

```
f = open('metadata.txt', 'r') #open file for reading

def build_data(f): #build dictionary

    output = {} #Dict
    for line in f.readlines(): #Iterates through every line in the string
        if "=" in line: #make sure line has data as wanted
            l = line.split("=") #Seperate by "=" and put into a list
            output[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip() #First word is key, second word is value

    return output #Returns a dictionary with the key, value pairs.

data = build_data(f)

print data["IMAGE_QUALITY"] #prints 9
```

Comment: Thanks DCaliber, that looks like what I m after but I couldnt get any output from it. Does this method require copying and pasting the contents of the metadata file? I need to be able to automate the process as I have 100s of images to work through.

Comment: I just edited it into a function. So you can get the value of the variables from the dictionary that is built. If you want a single dictionary file that contains all of the variable data from multiple sources then you make a nested dictionary. i.e data[file1][variable] = value